Coulomb Potential in Bhabha (fermion + anti-fermion) scattering
In computation of Coulomb potential of Bhabha (fermion + anti-fermion) scattering in Peskin and Schroeder QFT section 4.8 eq. (4.136), they only consider one Feynman $t$-diagram without claiming the reason why discarding the other possible $s$-diagram, as shown in the second figure. Does anyone know why we can discard it?
If we cannot discard the $s$-diagram, then would the Coulomb potential of fermion and anti-fermion be different with that of fermion and fermion, as computed in e.q. (4.133)



The second image you provide are two completely different processes based on how you are reading the time direction in the Feynman diagrams, why do you think they depict similar processes?

@Triatticus See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering, do you mean one is scattering and the other is annihilation? But how could we only consider scattering when computing Coulomb potential?

P&S are in eq. (4.136) considering the non-relativistic limit of Bhabha (fermion + anti-fermion) scattering where the scattering $t$-channel dominates over the annihilation $s$-channel: $|t| \ll |s|$.
